Evaluate $\lim_{x\to1-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\log\frac{1+x^n}{1+x^{n+1}}$ using Fubini Theorem?
I am trying to evaluate $\lim_{x\to1-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\log\frac{1+x^n}{1+x^{n+1}}$.
My attempt:I want to use Fubini Theorem.Set $0<x<1$
(1)$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\log\frac{1+x^n}{1+x^{n+1}}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\int_{x^{n+1}}^{x^n}\frac1{1+t}dt\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\int_x^1\frac{x^n}{1+yx^n}dy
\end{align}$$But I am stuck at summing up $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{1+yx^n}$$(2)Another way is to write the sum as follows:$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\int_{x^{n+1}}^{x^n}\frac1{1+t}dt=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\int_{\mathbb R_+}\chi_{[x^{n+1},x^{n}]}(t)\frac1{1+t}dt$$But again I find it hard to sum up $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\chi_{[x^{n+1},x^{n}]}(t)$$
Maybe we should apply another way instead of the Fubini Theorem?
Any help would be appreciated.

Numerically the limiting value seems to be approximately $0.306853$
(using Mathematica to evaluate the series for specific values of $x\lesssim 1$). That could be $1-\log 2$, but this is by no means definitive.

@peterag Did you mean $\log\frac{1+x^n}{1+x^{n+1}}=\log(1+x^n)-\log(1+x^{n+1})$?In this case,I write it as a integral $\int_{x^{n+1}}^{x^n}\frac1{1+t}dt$

Linking this one.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{1+yx^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^m y^m x^{(m+2)n}
=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^my^m}{1-x^{m+2}}$$
Integating with respect to $y$ from $x$ to $1$ term by term, we get
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m+1}\frac{1-x^{m+1}}{1-x^{m+2}}.$$
By L'Hospital rule, term by term limit at $x=1$ yields
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m+2}=1-\ln2$$

Instead of the function you wrote at the end, let us consider the slightly different map $$ f(t) := \sum_{n = 0}^\infty x^n \chi_{(x^{n + 1}, x^n]}(t),$$ which yields the same answer since integrals over a countable set are $0$. Note that the intervals $(x^{n+1}, x^n]$ are all disjoint, and thus any $t \in (0,1]$ lies in only one of these. So, only one term of this sum is going to be active, specifically the one with $n$ such that $x^{n+1} < t \le x^n$. Since the value taken is $x^n$, we notice from this that $f(t) \ge t,$ and also that $x f(t) \le t$. Of course, $f(t) = 0$ for all $t > 1,$ since in this case it does not hold that $t \in (x^{n+1},x^n]$ for any $n \ge 0.$
Now, defining $f$ as above and applying Fubini, the integral we are interested in is then $$ I(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{f(t)}{1+t} \mathrm{d}t.$$ Using the bounds on $f$ above, we find that for any $x \in (0,1)$, $$ \int_0^1 \frac{t}{1+t} \mathrm{d}t \le I(x) \le \frac{1}{x} \int_0^1 \frac{t}{1+t} \mathrm{d}t. $$ Now, squeezing as $x \to 1^-$ yields that $$\lim_{x \to 1^-} I(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{t}{1+t} \mathrm{d}t = 1 - \log(2).$$
